# A random sample of size 5 is drawn from the pdf $f_{Y}(y) = 2y, 0\leq y \leq 1$. Calculate $P(Y_{(1)} < 0.6 < Y_{(5)})$.

Tags: probability, statistics

A random sample of size 5 is drawn from the pdf $f_{Y}(y) = 2y, 0\leq y \leq 1$. Calculate $P(Y_{(1)} < 0.6 < Y_{(5)})$.
 (Hint: Consider the complement.)

Attempt: The pdf of the largest order statistics is $f_{Y_{max}(y)}$ = $f_{Y_{(n)}(y)}$ = $n[F_{Y}(y)]^{(n-1)}f_{Y}(y)$

And $f_{Y_{min}(y)}$ = $f_{Y_{(1)}(y)}$ = $n[1-(F_{Y}(y))]^{(n-1)}f_{Y}(y)$

Then given $f_{Y}(y) = 2y $ we can find the cdf $F_{Y}(y) = \int_{0}^{y} 2tdt = y^{2}$
Then with $n=5$ and using the pdf for the smallest order statistics we have find $f_{Y_{(1)}(y)}$ = $5[1-y^{2}]^{4}2y$ = $10y(1-y^{2})^{4}$
.
Can someone please help me? I was not sure how to put the complement form. I would really appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, so good.  (Note though, that the sample size $n$ is $5$.)

Integrate to find the  order statistics' cumulative distribution functions.

$$\begin{align}
F_{Y_{(1)}}(0.6) & = \int_0^{0.6}n[1-F_Y(y)]^{n-1}f_Y(y)\operatorname d y
\\[1ex] & = \int_9^{0.6} 10y(1-y^2)^4\operatorname d y & \because f_Y(y)=2y, F_Y(y)=y^2, n=5
\\[1ex] & = \biggl[-(1-y^2)^5\biggr]_{y=0}^{y=0.6}
\\[1ex] & = 1 - (1-0.6^2)^5
\\[4ex]
F_{Y_{(5)}}(0.6) & = \int_0^{0.6}n[F_Y(y)]^{n-1}f_Y(y)\operatorname d y
\\[1ex]
& = \int_0^{0.6} 10 y^{9}\operatorname d y
\\[1ex] & = 0.6^{10}
\end{align}$$

Next use your hint to "Consider the complement."

$$\mathsf P(Y_{(1)}< 0.6 \cap Y_{(5)}>0.6) = 1-\mathsf P(Y_{(1)}>0.6\cup Y_{(5)}<0.6)$$

Now, can you express this in terms of the order statistic CDFs?

Comment: Thank you for the help. And noticing that n = 5. I was really having trouble setting up the complement.